# how to I use below import statement in palantir foundry: import spark.implicits._

Tags: palantir-foundry

When I attempt to import spark.implicits._ in Global Code as below,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
import spark.implicits._
```

I get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<global-code>", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spark'
```

what is the proper statement in python transform in palantir foundry code repositories.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to run Scala code in Python Code Repositories.

Comment: Thanks @nicornk . I am new to spark and dont know scala at all. If you know, could you please share the equivalent of python.

Comment: The imports depend on what you want to achieve in your code. Are you following any guide or copying the code from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.implicits_` is for use with the scala language.  If you are new to Spark, and want to use python, I recommend you follow the guide on getting started in Python Transforms: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/getting-started/